# Django docker image only starts python shell

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - static_volume:/code/api/static
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=api.settings.production
    depends_on: 
      - redis
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A api worker -l warning
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=api.settings.production
    depends_on:
      - redis
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/api/static
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

which I use to build a docker image and push it to our gitlab docker registry with the following commands:

```
docker build -t foo/api-django .
docker push foo/api-django
```

This works without a problem. But as soon as I pull the image and run it using the following command

```
docker run -p 8000:80 -i -t foo/api-django
```

it just shows me the python shell of the image:
[image: docker image just shows python shell]

any advice? when i just run the docker-compose up it starts nginx, gunicorn etc. normally.

EDIT: here's my new dockerfile, which seems to work. but now, only gunicorn gets started, when I use `docker ps`

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE api.settings.production
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "collectstatic", "--no-input" ]
CMD [ "gunicorn", "-w", "2", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "api.wsgi:application" ]
```

Comment: try to add CMD in Dockerfile, from the screenshot it just open python console. `CMD [ "python", "manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application" ]

Comment: IF you add two `CMD` in dockerfile, only the last one will be executed. that is `CMD [ "gunicorn", "-w", "2", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "api.wsgi:application" ]` you can not have two `CMD` in dockerfile. if you are trying to start two process then you need to have some entrypoint

Comment: this may help if both are two different process `CMD ["sh","-c","python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application"]
`

Answer (score 1):

Here your command won't work because the command you are trying to execute(`python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application`) is inside `docker-compose` file.

You are suppose to run it via docker compose. Use

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build  # `docker-compose up` will work if your yml file is named `docker-compose.yml`
```

to build the images

And use the following command to run these containers:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up
```

You can use `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d` to run it as daemon mode.

**Or** you can put this command inside `Dockerfile` and remove it for compose file:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true
# rest of the code

CMD python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application
```

Then you should be able to run the docker using `docker run`. This is only for running the `web` container. It won't run the rest of the containers. If you update the CMD inside the `Dockerfile`, then make sure to remove that from `command` section of `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: multiple `CMD` won't work. You need to put one `CMD` which is for what will executed when the docker container is running. So you can use `CMD python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application` to run multiple commands in single CMD. More info can be found in documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: Or `CMD ["sh","-c","python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn -w 2 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 api.wsgi:application"]` would also work as per adii's suggestion

Comment: actually nginx, celery and redis also don't get started.

Comment: You need to use [**`docker-compose`**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) command to run all the docker containers in here :)